# Xcode generates "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0X0) " when ever It has Breakpoint near global Value

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have noticed that My Xcode generates "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0X0)"

when ever there is a break point at a value which is global. 
like in my case I was accessing a variable in other class, which I declared in another class named Global class to declare my all global Var there. Now am accessing it in another class, it shows Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0X0)

Due to this problem I am not able to debug things.

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: @Mani Didn't get your point?

Comment: Give more option to find out your error. Put break point and trace out your crash point

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide some code that exemplifies your crash? I'm a bit confused about what you mean as a "global var"

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere somehow you are accessing a deallocated variable, usually `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0X0)` stand for that, what do you mean by global variables, is your global class containing them already defined?

I think what you are locking for, is [Singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/), but maybe i`m wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well After discussion with few people,
**I checked the same breakpoints but for iOS7, in spite of iOS 6.1**

And yes there were no issues related "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0X0)" anymore.

So If you are having same issue while debugging for ios6.1 
you have to change the **debugging scheme**

Step.1 Click on Project(on the right side of Run, Stop button on the top of XCODE)
Step.2 Click on the Edit Scheme.
Step.3 Click on Debugger and change it to GDB from LLDB

That's it.

In case if you dont find GDB in step.3 , you may have to install it first
and then repeat the step.